# Persisting Group object not working iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, restful-url

I am adding a groups with events. Once I persist my Event object It adds it fine with no problems. When I persist my Groups The object dons pass over. I think it has something to do with my dictionary or adding the event to array of events.

```
if (!self.event) {
    self.event = [[Event alloc] init];
}

self.event.title = @"First Event";
self.event.location = @"Dun Laoghaire Cineama";
self.event.eventdate = @"2015-04-25 02:31 PM";
self.event.title = @"Cineama";
self.event.theevent = @"Cineama";
[[AppDelegate appDelegate].events persist:self.event];
```

//This works and creates the event.

```
NSMutableDictionary *groupsEventDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableArray *eventsJSONArray=[NSMutableArray array];

[groupsEventDict setValue:self.event._id forKey:@"_id"];
[groupsEventDict setValue:@"First Event" forKey:@"title"];
[groupsEventDict setValue:@"Dun Laoghaire Cineama" forKey:@"location"];
[groupsEventDict setValue:@"2015-04-25 02:31 PM" forKey:@"eventdate"];
[groupsEventDict setValue:@"Cineama" forKey:@"theevent"];
[groupsEventDict setValue:@"2015-05-25T09:36:31.139Z" forKey:@"created_at"];
[eventsJSONArray addObject:groupsEventDict];

self.group.groupName = @"Fake Group";
self.group.how = @"School";
self.group.howLong = @"5";
[self.group.events addObject:self.event];
[self.group.dictionaryofevents setObject:eventsJSONArray forKey:@"events"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"group.png"];
self.group.groupimage = image2;

[[AppDelegate appDelegate].groups persist:self.group];
```

//the error arrises here. A the self.group is not passed into my persist method as it returns instanly.

```
- (void) persist:(Group*)group
{
    NSLog(@"%@",group);

if (!group || group.groupName == nil || group.groupName.length == 0) {
    return;
}
if (group.groupimage != nil && group.groupimageId == nil) { 
    [self saveNewGroupImageFirst:group]; 
    return;
}
NSString* groups = [@"http://localhost:3000/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"groups"];
BOOL isExistingLocation = group._id != nil;

NSURL* url = isExistingLocation ? [NSURL URLWithString:[groups stringByAppendingPathComponent:group._id]] :
[NSURL URLWithString:groups];

NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = isExistingLocation ? @"PUT" : @"POST";

NSData* data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[group toDictionary] options:0 error:NULL];
request.HTTPBody = data;

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSArray* responseArray = @[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:NULL]];
        [self parseAndAddGroups:responseArray toArray:self.objects];
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you alloc and init your event object: `self.event = [[Event alloc] init];`

but do you also do that with your group object? i do not see anything like `self.group = [[Group alloc] init];`...

Comment: Thanks a million for your help by the way.

Comment: #define safeSet(d,k,v) if (v) d[k] = v;

Comment: would you like to share your project so i can take a look?

Comment: Yes, that would be very helpful. How will I forward it on? Thanks again.

Comment: maybe you can share it via dropbox?

Comment: I have them zipped and they will send via email. Dose that suit?

Comment: you better simply upload the project and share the link with me: http://www.zippyshare.com

Comment: There is the link there to the files. Thanks again. My aim is that every group has many events.

Comment: it is really hard to tell from seeing only some files cause i do not know which object is initialized at the time of calling nsjsonserialization and which not. i need the project to really help you finding that error, sorry...

Comment: Full project with server and the read me file to get the server up and running. Once the server is running the error will happen immediately, once the App is run.

Comment: the problem is in Group.m. in your `toDictionary` method you return a dictionary that contains a key "events" which contains an array of **Event** objects. those can of course not be converted to json...

Comment: Would you recommend to just use the dictionary of events and no "events" array at all? Thanks for your help.

Comment: no recommendation since i do not know your app and what you are trying to achieve :)